# azure cognitiveservices speech not working as I expected

Tags: python, azure, speech-to-text

I want to save the trascript of a file into a txt file but the file is created empty.
here is the code

```
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=audio_file)

speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
done = False

# Define a callback function to handle the result
def handle_result(result):
    print("Got result:", result.text)
    with open("transcript.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(result.text + "\n")



# Start the continuous transcription process
speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt.result.text)))
speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(handle_result)
speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))

speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
time.sleep(15) 
speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
```

I tried to put some print statements to see if the function is working correctly but The console only give me
RECOGNIZING: hello

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I received the same output as yours for the code below:-

```
import  azure.cognitiveservices.speech  as  speechsdk
import  time
import  os

speech_key  =  "<your-key>"
service_region  =  "<your-region>"
audio_file  =  "<path/to/your/audio/file.wav>"

speech_config  =  speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)

audio_config  =  speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=audio_file)

speech_recognizer  =  speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

done  =  False

def  main(result):

print(result.text)

for  result  in  result.text:

file  =  open("lco.txt", "w+")

file.writelines(result.text)

file.close

# Start the continuous transcription process

speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda  evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt.result.text)))

speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(main)

speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda  evt: print('RECOGNIZED event triggered'))

# speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(handle_result)

speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda  evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))

speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()

time.sleep(50)

speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
```

It's RECOGNIZING : **hello world**, but the text output is not sent to transcript.txt file.

**Output:**
[image]

I wrote another code for getting the transcript.txt file in my environment and it worked perfectly.

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech import AudioConfig, ResultReason, SpeechConfig, SpeechRecognizer
import os

speech_config = SpeechConfig(subscription="<your-key>", region="<your-region>")
audio_config = AudioConfig(filename="<path/to/your/audio/file.wav>")
speech_recognizer = SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()
if result.reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
    file_path = "<your-filename.txt>"
    with open(file_path, "w") as f:
        f.write(result.text)
else:
    print("Recognition failed: {}".format(result.reason))
```

**Output:**
[image]